how to prevent Get-Member to print the output in a Powershell script
I'm new in Powershell scripting and would like some help with this one.
I couldn't find anything so far.
I have the following code:
$responseInfo = Invoke-WebRequest -Method GET -Uri $uriInfo -Headers $headers 
echo "----------------------------------"
$responseInfo.Content
$nlwInfo = ConvertFrom-Json $responseInfo.Content
echo "----------------------------------"
$nlwInfo | Get-Member  
echo "----------------------------------"
echo $nlwInfo.front_url


This command "$nlwInfo | Get-Member" prints the output in the console.
Is there a way to avoid the output from being printed?
Thank you

Why do you want to run Get-Member in the first place, if you're not interested in the output?

Thanx the command is not required in order to get an attribute.
works also without it.

So ... why not just not run the command in the first place?

There are a couple of different ways to suppress stream output in PowerShell:
# assign to $null
$null = $nlwInfo | Get-Member

# cast to [void]
[void]($nlwInfo | Get-Member)

# pipe to Out-Null
$nlwInfo | Get-Member | Out-Null

In PowerShell version 7.x+ Out-Null will perform relatively fast, but for code targeting Windows PowerShell I'd suggest going with $null = ...

Problem solved.
the command is not required, in order to get a json attribute from the response
